# Making a kind of iframe with css overflow

Tags: html, css, overflow

I am facing a big css problem

I made a MDI system in html/jquery.
Inside the window clientzone I add html code with an ajax request and the use of the append method.

All is working fine.

My problem is about the code Inside the client zone.

You can see it here : http://jsfiddle.net/2P4Mb/1/

```
<div id="windowClientZone" style="height:300px; background-color:red; overflow:hidden;">
<div id="ajaxHtmlAppendedCode">
     <h1>Title</h1>

    <div id="ContentToBescrolled" style="overflow:scroll; background:yellow;">
        <ul id="MediaExplorer" class="gallery">
            <li class="DraggableItem">
                <div/>
            </li>
            <li class="DraggableItem">
                <div/>
            </li>

            <!-- ... -->


            <li class="DraggableItem">
                <div/>
            </li>
            <li class="DraggableItem">
                <div/>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have a content made with two parts : a title, and a wrap panel based upon an UL with floating.
I want the ul control to be scrollable and the title stay always visible.
i tried a lot of things with overflow/position asbolute but i not able to find a solution.

the ul zone is always greater than the window client zone.

Is there a way of making that easily ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: is this you are looking. http://jsfiddle.net/kheema/2P4Mb/2/

Comment: yes but without a specific height like "height:200px;"

Thanks

Comment: You can NOT have something with `height: auto` and `overflow: scroll` at the same time. Make a choice.

Comment: Thank you mr Lister, but my initial question was not "can we have something with height: auto and overflow: scroll at the same time ?" :)

Comment: @Vacrial Then it's not clear what you want. Does the `ContentToBeScrolled` have a fixed height or not?

Comment: Sorry for that Mr Lister, there were a lot of explanations with comments yesterday, but all disapears.

No fixed height, it is included inside a MDI Window made uppon a div and the Draggable method of the jquery.ui api.
So i need a responsibe layout and not a fixed height, the problem is there :/